# Intellij-idea access Bitbucket with several user names

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am working with bitbucket repository and getting the following error from intellij idea:

```
Remote URL test failed: remote error: 
Not licensed You do not have permission to access Bitbucket. 
Please contact your administrator to resolve this issue.
```

While connecting from git bash is successful.
In addition, didn't find where to define the bitbucket user in intellij.

Some additional info: I have two different accounts for two Bitbuket repos.
So, when tried on intellij console:

```
git config --list
```

I got in `user.name` the user name of previous repo.

Is there any elegant way to handle what user should be connected to git for each repository?

Comment: Do you use any custom plugin for bitbucket support?

Comment: no, but I also installed the bitbucket linky plugin

Comment: There is no BitBucket integration in IDEA. But you may try to use described workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88198#focus=streamItem-27-3570313.0-0

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I can access BitBucket.  You need to look at version control system (VCS) on the Top menu to interact with it.  Also look at Settings to provide URL and credentials.

Comment: I edited the question, the real problem here is to handle several user names when working on different repos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this was to generate an SSH key for the current repository and add it to the bitbucket server.
Now, when working with first repository - it works with the `user.name` and for second repository it's going with the SSH key.